# Get receipt notification by sending mail

Tags: c#, email

Here I am developing one desktop application using c# for sending mails. In that I want to add mail read notification. I have used the code below but it is not working. -- any help is greatly appreciated.

I have use it but does not work:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //txtFrom.Text = "test.common@gmail.com";
    try
    {
        MailMessage ms = new MailMessage();

        ms.To.Add(txtAddr.Text);
        ms.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);

        ms.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        ms.Body = txtBody.Text;

         ms.DeliveryNotificationOptions =
                         DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure |
                         DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess |
                         DeliveryNotificationOptions.Delay;
        ms.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "<test.common@gmail.com>");

        //if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        //{
        //    ms.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(
        //       FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.FileName));
        //}

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        //smtp.Host = "localhost";

        NetworkCredential cs = new NetworkCredential("test.common@gmail.com", "123");
        smtp.Credentials = cs;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Port = 587;

        smtp.Send(ms);

        Literal1.Text = "Your message has been sent...";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Literal1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: "but does not work:"  - care to elaborate? It's better than your previous attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158361/sending-email-and-get-response-from-the-user-if-it-has-read but please explain what's going wrong.

Comment: why do you have the angle brackets in your headers? did you remove it and try again? it should be test.common@gmail.com and NOT <test.common@gmail.com>. Did you also try a non gmail address? remember, it may "not work" if the client does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Gmail supports read reciepts for personal accounts.

Taken from [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1385059?hl=en):

> Read receipts are available only for Google Apps for Business, Education, and Government customers. They are not available in personal Gmail accounts. Upgrade now.