# python smtplib: how to use Disposition-Notification-To

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Hi there I've the following code:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Subject'] = "Test Email"
msg['From'] = "test@test.de"
msg['To'] = "test2@test.de"
msg['Disposition-Notification-To'] = "test@test.de"
if msgid is None:
    msgid = make_msgid()

msg['Message-ID'] = msgid
msg.attach(MIMEText(message, content_type))

server_ssl = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
server_ssl.ehlo()
server_ssl.login("test@test.de", "test123")

server_ssl.sendmail(user.email, ["test@test.de"], msg.as_string())
server_ssl.close()
```

It is sending the mail as expected but there is no "delivery receipt". I also tried it with "Return-Receipt-To" which seems to be just another "inofficial" standard...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This feature is not available for standard account [https://stackoverflow.com/a/20160844/3710490](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20160844/3710490)

Comment: It is a business account.

Comment: This feature has limitation: [https://support.google.com/a/answer/1385059?hl=en](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1385059?hl=en). Check if you `request read receipt` from Google acc directly, below the message appears `lightyellow` message: You have requested the read receipt. I tested: I wrote to friend (business acc) and he sent me receipt (clicking confirmation button). So your code is fine, its Google / program limitation o user decision